# AG Grid: Limit the number of characters user can enter in column filters

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an AG-Grid implementation where I would like to limit the number of characters user can enter(say 5 characters) when they are performing search on column filter.

Link: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/filtering/

I have tried using allowedCharPattern and cell Editor but both didn't helped me.

```
  allowedCharPattern: '\\d{0,5}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this happen in Ag-Grid way, use custom filter feature:

Check this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/qOiL8OZmlFNCJgFP?preview

I have added another listener in this example called keyPressedListener, nothing special it just restricts character count (applied for Athlete column)

```
const keyPressedListener = (event) => {
  if (event.target.value.length === 5) 
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

Further reading: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/component-filter/

NOTE: Please tweak the code for your preferred front end framework